# chrome.contextMenus: context menu entry for specific links only

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently I have a custom context menu entry <kbd>Login</kbd> when I right click on a link.
However, I wonder if there is a possibility to present my custom context menu entry only for specific types of links? Currently my code looks like this:

```
var context = 'link';
var title = 'Login';
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title,
                                     "contexts":[context],
                                     "onclick": login});
function login(e){
    var url = e.linkUrl;
    url += ((url.indexOf("?")>-1)?"&":"?") + "Login=admin&Password=admin";
    window.open(url);
}
```

I would like to have a context filter so that I could choose to show the entry only if the link has a certain format, e.g. `http://.../myspecificurl/...`.

Basically I need something like:

```
var context = 'link[href*=/myspecificurl/]';
```

or a callback upon rendering the context menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's documented as [targetUrlPatterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) using [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": title,
    "contexts": [context],
    "onclick": login,
    "targetUrlPatterns": ["http://*.example.com/*"]
});
```

Comment: I checked, it works. However I don't understand why I was not able to find it myself. Where is this targetUrlPatterns's documentation? Why this official link (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) doesn't mention it? How did you know about it, abraham?

Comment: Thanks man, I totally overlooked this. This is exactly what I needed. @Skalár it's listed as optional parameter of the according create/update/... functions. The patterns are quite teious to write though... a straight regex would be nice -.-

Comment: Now I have another problem... I need an exclusion pattern since regexes are not applicable here...